# Complex lookup in django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a class that has a number of fields, two of which are many-to-many fields:

```
class someClass(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    field3 = ...
    field4 = models.ManytoManyField(...)
    field5 = models.ManytoManyField(...)
```

I was originally hoping to use `someClass.objects.get(...)` later on:

```
someClass.objects.get(field1=..., field2=..., ...)
```

I would also like to limit the `someClass`es that get returned by field4 and field5 as well. I assume that I cannot do this in a `.get()` call because these represent many-to-many relationships that can take many forms.

At the time that I would have been looking to find a unique `someClass`, I would have access to several variables that correspond to objects represented in field1-field3, as well as two short lists of objects that correspond to the objects represented in field4 and in field5. These together should describe a unique instance.

Accepting that I may have to do this in a series of `.filter()`s, what is the best way for me to obtain the single `someClass` object that my data (again, one variable apiece for field1-field3 and two lists for field4 and field5) describes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is as obvious as you expect...

You definitely can't use `get` here because of the `m2m`s - you have to chain the filters to exclude results that contain inexact m2m matches.

```
query = someClass.objects.filter(field1=field1, field2=field2, field3=field3)

for item in list1:
   query = query.filter(foo=item)

for item in list2:
   query = query.filter(bar=item)

# substitute with fancy python as you wish.
```